# out put a model.wv with an if condition in a list

Tags: list, if-statement, syntax-error, word2vec

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import word2vec
mainmodel = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('C:/Users/user/2330.model')
data = open('C:/Users/user/vec_2330_segement.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8')
data=data.read()
```

Above is loading work2vec model and list of data 
Data is a huge of chinese vocabulary list ( have been cut in jieba , about 100 MegaByte ) but have two comma ',' between each whole document(news) , like :
["我" "是" "個" "帥" "哥" ,, "你" "也" "是" ,, "..."]
Have total 40,000 documents.
so , I hope what I see in result "doc_all".

FOR example(each vector in documents are 20 Dimensions)

0.12345 , 1.23456 , -2.34567 , ... , -3.45678

...

...

0.12345 , -1.23456 , 2.34567 , ... , 3.45678

(for 40000 rows)

```
data=data.read()
doc_all = []
doc_sent = []
for index in data:
    doc_sent.append(mainmodel.wv[index]),
    try:
        (doc_all if data[index] == ',').append(np.sum(doc_sent,axis=0)),        
    except KeyError:
        continue
len(doc_all)
```

which I can't believe is :
Why there comes an error from syntax , 
I have search lot of relate documents in flow but have no same situation ,
instead my code grammar is same  ,
have anything that I suppose to notice but I didn't ?

======Edit====== 
here is the tracebook (sorry for late) 
I guess it's need an else to break 
or... not ?

```
File "<ipython-input-3-c55175ca5d96>", line 9
(doc_all if data[index] == ',').append(np.sum(doc_sent,axis=0)),
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Share the syntax error. It'll help people helping you.

Comment: In addition to the syntax requested by @TedLyngmo, please remember to quote the exact error message.

Comment: I got it , thanks for your reminding me ! @RonDunn  & Ted Lyngmo

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking – it would help for you to go over your question and break things into short, clear sentences. What is 'jieba'? What do a few lines of `ver_2330_segement.txt` look like? (If it characters or vector values?) What is the *intent* of your code? What are you expecting `doc_all if data[index] == ','` to do? (I think that would be a syntax error no matter what. For example, try just `[] if True` in a Python interpreter; that 'if' alone is not proper Python syntax. It would at the very least require an `else`, like perhaps `[] if True else None`.)